# How to handle invalid Number in Javax validation for Spring Boot Rest and Jackson Deserializer

Tags: java, spring-boot, validation, jackson, spring-restcontroller

I have a Java Pojo class which is expected as a `@RequestBody` in my Rest Controller. This Java Pojo class has an Integer field.

When user is calling the Rest API and they pass Integer field value as a Junk String, then Jackson is throwing `InvalidFormatException`. I instead want to use Javax Validator framework annotation to handle this error and show a meaningful error message in response. Unfortunately Jackson deserialization from JSON to Java happens before Javax validation, therefore my `@Digits` validation never gets invoked.

Note, @NotNull gets invoked but @Digits is not getting invoked because jackson fails the request much before the call reaches Javax validation layer IMO.

Java Pojo class:

> ```
> public class Board implements Serializable{
>   private static final long serialVersionUID = 1L;
>
>
>   @Digits(message = "quantity must be a number", integer = 8, fraction = 0)
>   private Integer quantity;
>
>   public Integer getQuantity() {
>       return quantity;
>   }
>
>   public void setQuantity(Integer quantity) {
>       this.quantity= quantity;
>   }
> }
> ```

Controller class:

```
@Controller
@RequestMapping("boards")
public class EnrichController {

    @Autowired
    private BoardService boardService;

    @RequestMapping(value = "", method = RequestMethod.PUT, produces = "application/json;charset=UTF-8")
    public @ResponseStatus(value = HttpStatus.NO_CONTENT) @ResponseBody void updateBoard(
            @RequestBody @Valid Board board) throws IllegalArgumentException, MalformedURLException {
        boardService.updateUserBoard(board);
    }
}
```

User input:

```
{
  "quantity": "abcdef"
}
```

As you can see I am using Javax validation annotations `@Digits` & `@Valid` but no use because Jackson Deserialization fails while parsing the Integer field `quantity`.

Is there anyway you can help me to solve this situation by handling this use-case using Javax validation annotations? I reckon changing field type to String in POJO class is an expensive effort as we have to do String to Integer conversion everytime I need some business logic on that field, therefore that is not an option for me.

Comment: Add a `BindingResult` next to the `Board` argument, to capture errors and handle it inside your controller. Or write an `@ExceptionHandler` to provide proper error messages.

Comment: Thanks @M.Deinum, I already tried @ Exceptionhandler in ControllerAdvice class but it doesn't take care of my requirement of handling this particular use-case in Javax validation layer. In this case the error is always handled by Jackson parser.

Comment: And it always will be, unless you change the type to a `String` and validate that to be numeric. There is no way a non-integer, will be assigned to an integer for validation. What you want with your current setup is simply not possible.

Comment: So basically the value is asigned to the pojo and only afterwards the validation is run? This is so ugly. I would have thought the validation runs before trying to assign a value and then this scenario would perfectly work out. Stupid spring validation :( Actually if you send a string at least it shouldn't assign a number and you could validate NotNull, right?

Answer (score 2):

Well in your case the problem is that you're not conforming to the REST API exposed and try to send a string instead of a number for the quantity field. This should never happen either by you or a third party service that uses your API.

> Is there anyway you can help me to solve this situation by handling this use-case using Javax validation annotations?

In any case, if you still want to fix the above, a solution will be to change "quantity" in a string type field and and added pattern matching for it

```
@Pattern(message = "quantity must be a number", regexp="^[0-9]*$")
private String quantity;
```

Comment: Thank you, but Converting Pojo field from Integer to String is quite expensive. I can't afford that as it would require me to do Conversions manually everytime a Business logic code is required. I was looking more to find out if there exists framework level support to bypass this Jackson parse error on that particular field and instead handle it in Javax validation layer.

Comment: You're welcome. I agree with you there that's why I think you shouldn't concern that much with bypassing the Jackson, since if someone calls your API in that manner then they are doing it wrongly, and don't respect your API structure.
But in case you're integrating with a system and you know for sure that they are sending the data in that way and it's not gonna be changed anytime soon, then the only solution is to change it to string. Afterwards you can use [map struct](https://www.baeldung.com/mapstruct) to ease the conversion process.